# Cisco AnyConnect hangs on "Checking for profile updates..."

Tags: vpn, cisco, anyconnect

I have a Cisco AnyConnect accessing ASA 5510. The AnyConnect connection correctly authenticates and then hangs of "Checking for profile updates...".

The client (Vista64) is behind a firewall and can connect outside only via HTTP proxy. Wireshark shows that the authentication and initial setup correctly uses the system wide proxy, however, profile update does a direct tcp connection and of course - fails.

How to fix it?

Comment: Did this ever work? What are the versions of your ASA software and the anyconnect client images?

Comment: ASA 841-k8. AnyConnect 300857-k9. It works fantastic if no proxies are involved.